# issues installing/using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have installed Python 3.6 and have tried to install Beautiful Soup 4. After several issues the bs4 installation worked but every time I try and reference the bs4 installation with `from bs4 import beautifulsoup`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup'
```

I have set the PATH variable to point to the `python36-32` folder and the `bs4` folder has been created in `python36-32\lib\site-packages`.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you.

Comment: Thanks, Glader. Not sure how to "accept" an answer but yours worked a treat. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to import is `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

If you look at [the examples in the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) you can see how to use it.